# Python /n separated lines

Tags: python, pandas

i've been running this code :

```
df = pd.read_csv('filepath\\out(noid).csv')
g = df.groupby(['date','user_id'])
g = g['business_id'].unique()
```

my file has data about dates and users that went to some business id (comma separated) an example:

> 18/4/2013,-6rEfobYjMxpUWLNxszaxQ,cE27W9VPgO88Qxe4ol6y_g
>   6/1/2013,EZ0r9dKKtEGVx2CdnowPCw,mVHrayjG3uZ_RLHkLj-AMg
>   22/7/2013,fvTivrsJoUMYXnOJw9wZfw,wJr6kSA5dchdgOdwH6dZ2w

then i execute the following code:

```
dataf = pd.DataFrame(g).reset_index()
newdf = dataf['business_id'].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
x1 = dataf['business_id'][newdf]
x1.to_csv('filepath\\output.csv')
```

i am looking for groups of date/user_id that went to some business_ids and at least this seems to work but i have problem with the output file. My output file when it finds more than 3 business_ids for one group it splits them into separated lines and i don't want that because i can't use it later on my code. An example is :

> 26,"['G0nUhYF2q4tnoOPwCjXLig' 'nnPrX9mNtV5jKpo2cMjPWQ'
>   'ZgWUM594Yqk52IvBgoIrdA'  'HMr_KN63f6MzM9h8Wije3Q'
>   'ripCiWZ0MblMZSLrIKQAKA' 'jcI4ZPF3-hSUPsnoqRHO4w' 
>   '0InQd9vuhRc98OksC3Ks8Q' 'nC36M3EGG5jDXC6JLh_9EA'
>   'pG9AXrNWpjhX8p4Bz7bLrA'  'BuJ40Y7c_ERYmkQGoFb8zQ'
>   'JpHE7yhMS5ehA9e8WG_ETg' 'rBCX6nU2ub6v8ErfzXyjtg' 
>   '9SrR4mkEsyimsimrc-vP4w']"

when i would like all of them to be in one line and not in separated lines. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: ...and yourlist is generated with json-module?

Comment: i had a json file from where i got the data. then i converted into csv and read it to take the info i wanted. assuming i understood your comment correctly you suggest that i write `x1 = dataf['business_id'].join(newdf)`
instead of `x1 = dataf['business_id'][newdf]` ? in that case i got the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'` @palsch

Comment: join is a bit strange. You write connextorstr.join(thelist). So only strings have a join function. Have a look at the python docs to join (sry, I have no time to Google it and give you a link) @Fotis

Comment: no problem @palsch i will look it up thanks in advance. will see if it worked

Comment: did it work? Or did you get wrong results?

Comment: no it didnt worked...googled it but didnt had any results :/

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm @Fotis ?